# Get values from NSUserDefaults in Swift class

Tags: ios, swift3

I have stored a value in NSUserDefaults in Objective-C class , now i want to get that value in another class which is Swift Class , i have tried but null comes there, how can i get the value from Objective-C class to Swift Class.

Comment: can you please, show me your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NS]UserDefaults is backed by a plist and a dictionary. The Objective-C   string was saved to the plist as a Some Text.

That same plist loaded in Swift gives a string for that key.

So you should have no issue using UserDefaults.string to read the value   stored with Objective-C. Of course you still need to verify the value   actually exists.

```
if let str = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "textKey") {
     print("Found \(str)")
  } else {
     print("No string for key")
  }
```

Even if the original value isn't a string, using UserDefault.string is safe. It will simply return nil for non-string values.

With regard to NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary, note that UserDefaults only retrieves immutable NSDictionary. You can't read an NSMutableDictionary (or array) from UserDefaults.

Note you can safely use a Swift dictionary to read the original NSDictionary. No need to use Objective-C classes.

Comment: thanks a lot , i got it.@Hrishikesh